# How to use bindmodel in controller in cakephp 3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to use bindModel in cakephp 3.x using below code:

```
$this->Member->bindModel([
               [
                 'hasMany'=>[
                     'NpoMember' =>[
                      'className' => 'NpoMember',
                      'foreignKey' => 'member_id',
                      'conditions' => ['NpoMember.status' => 'Active'],
                  ]         
               ]
            ]
        ]);
```

but it is throwing error. Please suggest the correct syntax to bindmodel in controller in cakephp 3.x

Comment: Can you share the error and stack trace from the error log

Comment: Why on earth are people blinding stumbling into a new major version of a framework without reading *anything*? Seriously, why do you expect this to work? And you "forgot" to post the error as well. Well, I know what error you get... Read the migration guide https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-x-migration-guide.html and do a tutorial for it to become familiar with it. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html What I suggest you: Start reading docs before writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work using contains after adding association in model. then you can add any number of binding using contain and . operator example:

```
$getPlaylistItems= $this->MyPlaylists->find()->where(['user_id'=>$_POST['user_id'],'section'=>$_POST['section']])
        ->contain(['PlaylistItems','PlaylistItems.DbArtists'])
        ->hydrate(false)->toArray();
```

Comment: @Er Gagandeep Sethi you know who is Gagzzz

Comment: @kunal yes I know him